# git strategy when sharing work in progress with another developer

Tags: git

I have some repo with code, and there is a `mymaster` branch.

There is another developer that is doing work locally in his `myfeature` branch (which starts from the `mymaster` branch)

He has pushed his work to the repo and I could see that some things need a correction.

So I created a local branch `mycorrection` in which I corrected some parts of the code.

Now, I have not finished yet but I would like he to see the modifications so far , so that he is aware of this.

What is the best git strategy to do this?

---

I have thought of pushing `mycorrection` to the repo and make him fetch that branch to his own local repo. However I will keep commiting to this branch so I am not sure if this is the best approach.
In the end I will merge `mycorrection` to `mymaster` so how would that impact his work?

Comment: So basically `mycorrection` is the branch that only contains the corrections to `myfeature`? There is no problem in pushing your branch and updating it with commits. The only thing I find confusing, is why you want to merge it to the `mymaster`. It is much better to integrate branches `myfeature` and `mycorrections` and after such integration merge it to the `main` branch.

I'm also worried that this question can be labelled as opinion based.

Comment: `my correction` is correcting work that is already done in `mymaster`. He is working new features in `myfeature`

Comment: You need to clarify the question you asked then, as it states that 'I could see that some things need a correction', which rather indicates that you want to fix changes on his branch.